# Items in localStorage appear briefly but disappear after redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, browser, local-storage

I'm working on a React app that's currently deployed on Azure App service. I've got a log in system that worked in my dev environment but now is having issues saving user display data upon successful login.

Basically, I'm making a standard POST req to log in. It looks like this:

```js
fetch('api...', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
  credentials: 'include'
})
.then(res => return res.json())
.then(...)
```

In that second `.then(...)` block after I've received data back from the server, I have this logic:

```js
if (!data || !data.success) {
  // set error message and return
} else {

  // Save the user display data so things like the Menubar can access it easily
  localStorage.setItem('displayName', data.displayName);
  localStorage.setItem('avatarRef', data.avatarRef);
  localStorage.setItem('username', data.username);

  // (A debug console.log() of the data received from server here)

  // Redirecting to account page after 100ms here
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = '/account';
  }, 100);
}
```

When I access the deployed website from my browser and log in, my authentication (cookies, etc.) are working, but these `displayName` etc. fields are briefly appearing in my localStorage before I get redirected from `/account/login` to `/account`.

By the way, when I console log the display name, etc., I do see the correct values in Devtools' console. So I am indeed receiving the data, the browser just isn't setting it correctly. I've tried this on both Chrome and Edge.

Theories for why the data isn't persisting:

- Maybe I'm redirecting so fast that the localStorage hasn't fully set in yet?
- Is the data disappearing as a consequence of using `window.location.href` instead of a redirect status code or some other redirection method?

If anyone has any general pointers as to where the issue might be here, I might be able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an Incognito window? Are you using `https://`? Does anything appear in the "Issues" tab in Chrome devtools? Do you notice anything if you have "Preserve Log" checked in the Network tab?

Comment: do you have `localStorage.clear()` in your code? Perhaps it's executing on re-direct. as for your theories, `Maybe I'm redirecting so fast` no. `as a consequence of using window.location.href` no.

Comment: @Dai `Are you using https://` irrelevant. localStorage isn't restricted to secure contexts

Comment: @JaromandaX Correct, _but_ insecure contexts don't share cookies with secure-contexts - so a secure-context-switch _could_ lead to the invocation of application code that clears localStorage. My question was posed to explore all possibilities, and not because I was suggesting that `localStorage` only works on `https:` sites.

Comment: why would the app got from https to http? makes zero sense for a single app to do that @Dai

Comment: @JaromandaX Corp and on-prem networks are full of `http`-only services.

Comment: sure . but that's completely and utterly irrelevant to this question @Dai